# ¿How to make Parent Child ordering with Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

I need to render the data like parent -> child (Rows). I have an action button that create a new row below it.

**Example:**

1 PETER GREGORY 01/01/1987

2 MINK PETERS 01/01/1987 (CLICKED HERE)

3 CHILD ROW 01/01/1987

**My database has this columns:**

ID ------ NAME ------ LASTNAME ------ DATE

Comment: order by id_parent instead? **edit** nvm you want id 480 above 478?

Comment: yes, i need all the id_parents to be above of inserted row. Example, if i add a row in 479, the new row has to be below it ordered by date (because if user insert multiple rows for 479 parent

Comment: I'm still grasping at the full question you have but from what I understand it sounds like your sql should be `select * from test.test order by id_parent, date` this way the id_parent will always be grouped together and then it will order it by the dates.

Comment: Hello andrei, thanks for your patience, Asuming that i add a new row clicking the 469 row, the new row has to be below it. Can you undestand me now?

Comment: ah, this makes more sense. so you want to insert **id = 470, id_parent = 283** for example?

Comment: Yes, every new row will have id_parent of the above row. If i click to add in the row 50, the NEW row will have id_parent 50. So when i do the select, will show row 50 and below this row and his other childs

Comment: there is a few things you can do. although it's bad practice to change the primary key once it's inserted unless you have a specific edge case. Generally the primary Id is an *entity* or uniqueidentifier is *MSSQL* and in *PostgreSQL* you would use  SERIAL which means on every new row it will find the next available id to insert. you would need to join back onto the same table to get the results you are probably looking for. In your web app, you have multiple rows, and each row can have children rows and etc.. you have a recursive join. so the parent table is the same table of the child key

Comment: `select p.id, c.id from test.test p join test.test c on  p.id = c.id_parent` should get you the parent id's associated to it's child reference.

Comment: Hello Andrei, im not changing the index id. What i need to accomplish is when i add a new row, the new one has to stay in the position was created.

Comment: any reason? you'll eventually run out of space of the id's so between 469 and 478 you can insert about 9 available id's that are available  for parent_id 283. What is going to happen when you need to insert another child 283?

Comment: you can do `insert into (id, id_parent[, rest of columns I can't see]) values(470, 283[, rest of columns values I can't see])`

Comment: How can i do to then?. Did you have another side to make it?. I only want to make a tree of rows.

Comment: can you post 5 rows of the full data just do `select top 5 * from test.test` and i'll put together an answer I believer I understand what you need, add it to your original post so it's easier to see

Comment: ok. give me a second please

Comment: im uploading the photo

Comment: check the photo andrei

Comment: updated post, please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

firstly you would have to have the database I'm going to create a generic one

```
-- this will create your table + primary key (i'm not sure what action data type is)
create table test (
 id serial PRIMARY KEY,
 id_parent integer,
 col1 text
)
```

on each insert you will be auto generating the **id** field because it is a serial and you wont need to add it in the insert statement

lets assume you already have root parents meaning that the id_parent value is null

root id = 1, 2, 3

- `INSERT INTO test (id_parent, col1) values (null, 'I'm parent 1')`
- `INSERT INTO test (id_parent, col1) values (null, 'I'm parent 2')`
- `INSERT INTO test (id_parent, col1) values (null, 'I'm parent 3')`

so when you want to insert values you will simply run the query

`INSERT INTO test (id_parent, col1) values (1, 'parent id is 1')`

the above insert statement will auto generate the **id** field because it is a serial.

if we insert a few more records

- `INSERT INTO test (id_parent, col1) values (1, 'parent id is 1')`
- `INSERT INTO test (id_parent, col1) values (1, 'second insert parent id is 1')`
- `INSERT INTO test (id_parent, col1) values (2, 'first insert parent is 2')`
- `INSERT INTO test (id_parent, col1) values (2, 'second insert parent id is 2')`

you should have 7 records in the db now, the 3 root parents and the 4 children we have inserted

to retrieve your data you will want to reference back onto the parent column via join statement

```
select 
  parent.id
 ,child.id
 ,child.parent_id 
from test parent
  join test child = parent.id = child.id_parent
order by child.parent_id
```

you'll get something that looks like

```
parent.id | child.id | child.parnet_id
1         | 4        | 1
1         | 5        | 1
2         | 6        | 2
2         | 7        | 2
```

then if you do another insert for parent_id 1 via

- `INSERT INTO test (id_parent, col1) values (1, 'parent id is 1')`

you'll get

```
parent.id | child.id | child.parnet_id
1         | 4        | 1
1         | 5        | 1
1         | 8        | 1
2         | 6        | 2
2         | 7        | 2
```

this is the general basics if you want to use the same table for a recursive join. I hope the helps? also I haven't tested any of the code so there might be a few syntax errors but that's the general idea

Comment: Hello andrei, i make a new improved question

Comment: hey @osmelg my solution should still be enough to get started to figuring out your exact case. you can modify the create and insert statements to support the extra data. But the end results should give you a good idea where to pick off and continue.

Comment: Hello. Can you understand perfectly now?. What more I need to do with your query to solve my problem?